# Selenium Chrome Driver: How to fix the error I`m getting when trying to add proxy?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have following code, defining **Web3Driver class** which I later use in my code. Web3Driver is simular to regular **selenium driver** object, but with special properties and parameters like individually assigned proxy, fingerprint, etc:

```
class Web3Driver:
    def __init__(self, wallet_id):
        self.wallet = db.get_wallet(wallet_id)
        self.mnemonic = self.wallet[2]
        possible_symbols = string.ascii_letters + string.digits
        combination_length = 15
        self.password = ''.join(random.choice(possible_symbols) for _ in range(combination_length))
        user_agent = self.wallet[13]
        chrome_options = Options()
        chrome_options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
        chrome_options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ['enable-automation'])
        chrome_options.add_argument(f'user-agent={user_agent}')
        chrome_options.add_extension('10.33.0_0.crx')
        service = Service('chromedriver.exe')
        webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
            "httpProxy": f'{self.wallet[12]}',
            "proxyType": 'MANUAL',
        }
        driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
        self.driver = driver
        self.wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10)
        logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format="%(asctime)s %(levelname)s %(message)s",
                            datefmt="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", filename=f"wallet_{wallet_id}.log")
```

It creates object of web3driver which is used in my code later.
When I initiate object of Web3Driver class for the first time with `web3driver = Web3Driver(wallet_id)`, everything works ok and after initiation, methods of web3driver also work. But after selenium driver is closed, later in my program I initiate a new object of Web3Driver class with `web3driver = Web3Driver(wallet_id)`. And now an exception arises...

```
Exception in thread Thread-1 (manage_tasks):
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 1038, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\threading.py", line 975, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\manage_tasks.py", line 92, in manage_tasks
    tasks.bridge_to_zksync(task[0])
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\tasks.py", line 10, in bridge_to_zksync
    web3driver = Web3Driver(wallet_id)
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\selenium_driver.py", line 45, in __init__
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service, options=chrome_options)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 49, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 54, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 206, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities)
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 291, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, caps)["value"]
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 346, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\childoflogos\Desktop\airdrop_hunter\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 245, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: cannot parse capability: proxy
from invalid argument: unrecognized proxy type: MANUAL
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
    GetHandleVerifier [0x006AA813+48355]
    (No symbol) [0x0063C4B1]
    (No symbol) [0x00545358]
    (No symbol) [0x0055B42D]
    (No symbol) [0x005603E4]
    (No symbol) [0x0055A99B]
    (No symbol) [0x0058FCEE]
    (No symbol) [0x0058F9A8]
    (No symbol) [0x00590AD7]
    (No symbol) [0x0059093C]
    (No symbol) [0x0058A536]
    (No symbol) [0x005682DC]
    (No symbol) [0x005693DD]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0090AABD+2539405]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0094A78F+2800735]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x0094456C+2775612]
    GetHandleVerifier [0x007351E0+616112]
    (No symbol) [0x00645F8C]
    (No symbol) [0x00642328]
    (No symbol) [0x0064240B]
    (No symbol) [0x00634FF7]
    BaseThreadInitThunk [0x769800C9+25]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77927B4E+286]
    RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77927B1E+238]
```

The way I am adding proxy to selenium driver capabilities seems right (and it does actually work without any exception, but only for the first time). What might be causing this mistake and how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Specify all necessary fields for a "MANUAL" proxy setting and then eliminate what you may not need, I suspect it is the `"autodetect"` that may be required:

```py
webdriver.DesiredCapabilities.CHROME['proxy'] = {
    "httpProxy": f'{self.wallet[12]}',
    "ftpProxy": f'{self.wallet[12]}',
    "sslProxy": f'{self.wallet[12]}',
    "noProxy": None,
    "proxyType": 'MANUAL',
    "autodetect": False
}
```

Comment: I changed my code like according to your solution, yet still the same error arises (strangely, only after I initiate object of Web3Driver for the first time, quit it and then initiate in again)

Comment: Strange,  wonder if there is a stale session. When you say quit, do you mean ```self.driver.quit()```, to ensure the session has been quit completely. I guess you are, based on your comment.